# How to pass an array to a function in MIPS Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

So the assignment is to write a function in MIPS that takes an array, adds all the contents of the array together, and returns the sum. The main problem is that I'm new to Assembly and not entirely sure how to pass an array to the function in Assembly, here's what I have so far:

```
# Title: homework2.asm
# Author: Jacob Suarez
# Date: 9/28/14
# Purpose: Create a function that can find the sum of the elements in an array, and run two arrays through it

# Text Segment
.text          
.globl  __start 
__start: 

    li  $t0, 0         # $t0 <- sum
    li  $a0, 0         # $a0 <- array index

# Set arr1 as the argument for the sumArr function
    la  $t4, arr1
    sw  $t4, arrx

# Set upper bound of array index
    li  $t9, 4         

# Call function to calculate the sum of arr1
    jal sumArr

    sw  $v0, sum1
    la  $a0, sum1

# Print sum1 from $a0
    li      $v0, 1         
    syscall 
    la      $a0, end1
    li      $v0, 4 
    syscall 

# Reset function arguments to 0
    li  $t0, 0         # $t0 <- sum
    li  $a0, 0         # $a0 <- array index

# Set arr2 as the argument for the sumArr function
    la  $t4, arr2
    sw  $t4, arrx

# Set upper bound of array index
    li  $t9, 5         

# Call function to calculate the sum of arr2
    jal sumArr

    sw  $v0, sum2
    la  $a0, sum2

# Print sum2 from $a0
    li      $v0, 1         
    syscall 
    la      $a0, end2
    li      $v0, 4 
    syscall 

# End program
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall

sumArr:
    lw  $t2, arrx($a0)  # $t2 <- value in the array
    add $t0, $t0, $t2   # sum += A[i]
    addi    $a0, $a0, 4 # i++ in bytes
    blt $a0, $t9, sumArr

# Move contents of $t0 to $a0
    move    $t0, $a0

# Return
    jr  $ra

# Data Segment
    .data 
    arrx:   .space  100
    arr1:   .word   8,12,20,40
    arr2:   .word   15,25,35,55,-129
    sum1:   .word   0
    sum2:   .word   0
    end1:   .asciiz " is the sum of arr1.\n"
    end2:   .asciiz " is the sum of arr2.\n"
# end of file  homework2.asm
```

Now, this all runs fine, but the problem is that the results seem to just be pulled from an uninitialized space in memory, so I just get numbers like 4268501128 or whatever that are obviously wrong, so I think my problem is how I'm passing the array to the function, specifically this part of the code:

```
# Set arr1 as the argument for the sumArr function
    la  $t4, arr1
    sw  $t4, arrx
```

Any tips? Or is my problem something else entirely?

Edit: I think my problem might actually be that the arrays are not initialized properly, or how I'm getting data from it, but I can't figure out if that's actually the case because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong about how I initialized them.

Comment: To pass an array to a subroutine, you have two choices: Push a complete copy of the array onto the stack (pass-by-value, usually not the right answer), or push the array's base address onto the stack and then address relative to that (pass-by-reference). Don't forget that the subroutine also needs to know the dimensions of the array so it can do the appropriate relative addressing calculations; that can either be hardcoded or additional arguments. If you're seeing the wrong data, your addressing is wrong... or you really didn't initialize the array.

Comment: Okay, I was trying to pass the address of arr1 and arr2 to arrx but I guess I must have been going  about it the wrong way. Guess I'll keep trying while I wait for more answers.

Comment: I didn't think you could ```sw $t4,arrx```, I'm pretty sure you need to do ```la $??,arrx sw $t4,($??)``` since MIPS can't load/store directly to/from memory I believe.

Answer (score 0):

So you've got this part correct:

```
# Set arr1 as the argument for the sumArr function
la  $t4, arr1
```

But unfortunately this part is wrong:

```
sw  $t4, arrx
```

MIPS is known as a RISC (Reduced Instruction Set Computer) meaning that it has fewer instructions than a computer like Intel's x86. One thing that MIPS cannot do is store a register directly to a constant address like this. In order to store `$t4` at address `arrx`, you'll need to do something like this. (Note that for this example I chose `$t3` just because it hasn't been used yet.)

```
la $t4,arr1    ;load the address of arr1 into $t4
la $t3,arrx    ;load the address of arrx into $t3
sw $t4,0($t3)  ;store the address of arr1 at the first 4 bytes of arrx
```

After this sequence of instructions, our data segment would look like this (if you could somehow see the `.data` portion of your source code update in real time as your code runs):

```
.data 
    arrx:   .word arr1
            .space  96
    arr1:   .word   8,12,20,40
    arr2:   .word   15,25,35,55,-129
    sum1:   .word   0
    sum2:   .word   0
    end1:   .asciiz " is the sum of arr1.\n"
    end2:   .asciiz " is the sum of arr2.\n"
```

Comment: Some MIPS assemblers, including MARS/SPIM, assemble `lw` or `sw $reg, symbol` to `lui`/`sw`, using `$at` for the high half of the address.  i.e. they support it as a pseudo-instruction like `la` always is.  Using a separate `la` + `sw` or `lw` takes a total of three instructions, so it's only better if you're going to reuse the address.  (Or if you want students to make sure they understand what the machine can actually do.)